# Inserting field-based hyperlinks in non-spatial tables

Tags: arcgis-desktop, polygon, attribute-table, hyperlink

I am trying to insert field-based hyperlinks into a non-spatial table in arc 10.3.  The idea is simple, open the table and click on the link.  I am able to add hyperlinks to spatial fields, and click on a polygon to open it, but my map is very complicated and it does not make sense for users to have to click all over the map to get the correct one.  Also, the user will not know where they are supposed to click because it is a world map where states have ownership of polygons, lines, and points, in various locations around the globe.

When I right click the table, the display tab does not have the option to enable hyperlinks the way it does with a feature class.

There must be some very simple way to do this that I am missing, but for the life of me I cannot figure it out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I do not believe the capability to have a functional hyperlink within an ArcGIS attribute table is supported. Having the path as a field value the user can highlight -> right-click -> copy -> paste may be the best option.